# Hacer 'dig' a una lista de DNS e IP para comprobar si coinciden

Tags: linux, bash, script, shell

Tengo una lista de direcciones DNS e IP con el siguiente formato:

```
DNS IP
DNS IP
DNS IP
```

Y necesito un script que haga el comando `dig +short DNS` (Donde DNS es la DNS de una fila de la lista) y comprobar si coincide con la dirección IP que hay justo después de esta misma DNS en la misma línea; eso con todo el documento. La idea es mostrar la misma, pero con un "coinciden" justo después, `$DNS y $IP coinciden.` si coinciden, o un mensaje de error si no es así.

He probado con

```
awk '{ DDD=$(dig +short $1); if ( $DDD == $2 ); then; print "'$DDD' y '$2' coinciden."; fi }' all.log
```

Pero el resultado muestra:

```
(espacio) y (espacio) coinciden.
(espacio) y (espacio) coinciden.
(espacio) y (espacio) coinciden.
```

Comment: Hi Rayclank, this is a spanish site for stackoverflow, if you want a correctly answer you have to go and ask in this site [clic here](https://stackoverflow.com/) or you can translate your question to spanish and wait for an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema en tu one-liner en awk es la asignación de la salida del comando a la variable `DDD`, pero principalmente es por tu uso de las comillas simples dentro del programa de awk.
`$DDD` y `$2` no tienen almacenado algo fuera de awk.

Algo que puedes hacer es utilizar un script completo de bash así.

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r DNS IP || [[ -n "$DNS" && -n "$IP" ]]
do
    grep -q "$IP" <<< "$(dig +short $DNS)"

    [[ "$?" == 0 ]] \
        && resultado="$resultado\n$DNS,$IP,Coincide" \
        || resultado="$resultado\n$DNS,$IP,No coincide"
done < all.log

echo -e "$resultado" | column -ts ,
```

El comando `grep` lo sugiero porque a veces vienen más de un registro `A`, entonces comparar con una igualdad la IP que tienes registrada en tu archivo siempre resultará negativo, aunque haya un patrón que coincida.

Por ejemplo, okcupid tiene varios registros A. Para asegurarse que esté ahí, se busca el patrón con `grep`.

La ejecución del script da como resultado.

```
$ ./dig.sh
google.com    216.58.193.14    Coincide
google.com    0.0.0.0          No coincide
yahoo.com.mx  124.108.115.101  Coincide
okcupid.com   198.41.209.131   Coincide
okcupid.com   0.0.0.0          No coincide
```

De un archivo `all.log` de la forma.

```
google.com 216.58.193.14
google.com 0.0.0.0
yahoo.com.mx 124.108.115.101
okcupid.com 198.41.209.131
okcupid.com 0.0.0.0
```